# Nickel(II) + borohydride debenzylation reaction mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, transition-metals, catalysis

I've been looking at [this reaction for cleavage of benzyl esters](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/abstracts/lit2/495.shtm). I've also looked at the [original paper](https://www.thieme-connect.de/DOI/DOIhttps://www.thieme-connect.de/DOI/DOI?10.1055/s-0028-1087982) and some others, but haven't been able to find any mechanism on how this reagent does hydrogenation.

It also works with Cbz-protected amines/amides/alcohols. With palladium/platinum, the transition metal does oxidative insertions into the X-Bn bond, but I'm not sure nickel could do this insertion. If it could, I would expect this reagent to debenzylate amines, amides and ethers in addition to esters, carbamates and carbonates.

I was wondering if it is known how this reagent debenzylates esters or if anyone has any insight into the mechanism.